# DownloadManager download failed

Tags: java, android

Can't download mp3 file from this link http://31.186.48.72/media/audio/a_209353.mp3
but can download from this link 
https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/AndroidDownloadManager.mp3 using android.app.DownloadManager.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(DOWNLOAD_FILE);
    Log.d("download", "downloading....");
    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    String fileName = "testmp3";
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
    request.setTitle(fileName);
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"test.mp3");
    downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Here is the cursor result

```
_id=8
local_filename=null
mediaprovider_uri=null
destination=4
title=testmp3
description=
uri=http://31.186.48.72/media/audio/a_209353.mp3
status=403
hint=file:///mnt/sdcard/Download/test.mp3
media_type=null
total_size=-1
last_modified_timestamp=1511346244441
bytes_so_far=0
local_uri=null
reason=placeholder
```

Comment: failed 403 error

Comment: Can't figure out why it's giving me this error. But I'm able to download using browser. The link is working.

Comment: have attached cursor dump result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a restriction on server side to download manager.

Comment: I see, and how did you removed the restriction? Mind adding that to your answer?

Comment: @DarkCygnus We've website and mobile app. I don't control server side. I contacted to the site administrator and he said he had allowed download only from website but  he couldn't remember how did it.

Answer (score 3):

Your first link is giving 403 error and hence you are not able to download

Comment: But I'm able to download using browser.

Comment: Your browser must be passing session information (cookies) which you don't have it here.

Answer (score 0):

Status, such as reason, is integer fields, not String. As I see, reason=placeholder, and you need write cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON)) for reason, not getString, and cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) for status, after you should see actual error reason, and this will be not 403 http code